# Switching Dictation Input Language

Tags: languages, gboard

What options do I have to switch the input language for dictation? Is it only tied to the keyboard?

Is it possible to switch to German dictation but still keep the English keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it's possible to set a QUERTY keyboard for German. Not an ideal solution but better than having to switch back to English all the time.